# Pymongo invalid syntax near $gte

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using Pymongo. I have successfully connected to my MongoDB. Collection name is `test_collection`. In the document, there is a key called `request_time` . I am trying to fetch the documents in a specific range of `request_time`.

In the mongodb shell, this command works,

```
db.getCollection('test_collection').find({ request_time: { $gte: new Date('2018-06-22'), $lt: new Date('2018-06-26') }});
```

But, when I am using pymongo. It is not accepting `$` and giving syntax error.

```
collection = db['test_collection']

cursor = collection.find({request_time: { $gte: new Date('2018-06-22'), $lt: new Date('2018-06-26') }})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write commands in Javascript in mongo shell, don't copy-paste them into python.
Python is not Javascript.

Python does not have neither `new` nor builtin `Date` type.

[`find`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) method of the `pymongo.collection.Collection` class expects dictionary with string keys, put keys in quotes.

Use [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) if respective fields in documents from the mongo collection are `ISODate`s.

```
import datetime 
cursor = collection.find({"request_time": { 
                          "$gte": datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 22), 
                          "$lt": datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 26) }
                         })
```

Answer (score -1):

Use **'$gt'** and **'$lt'** in code.

```
cursor = collection.find({request_time: { '$gte': new Date('2018-06-22'), '$lt': new Date('2018-06-26') }})
```

Comment: It is now showing request_time not defined. request_time key is present in the document itself. Do I need to define it somehow ?

Comment: Pymongo receives all functions and fields as strings. So the final query would be cursor = collection.find({'request_time': { '$gte': new Date('2018-06-22'), '$lt': new Date('2018-06-26') }})

Comment: python doesn't have neither `new` nor builtin `Date` type

Answer (score -2):

Try put brasket in each condition

({ { $gte: new Date('2018-06-22') }, { $lt: new Date('2018-06-26') } })

Comment: Just for sanity check... replace quotes to double quotes

Comment: or try put double quotes at $gt and $lt